# ¿Como podría mejorar la eficiencia mi programa de contar letras?

Tags: java, revisión-de-código

Se trata sobre un menú contador el cual deberá contar vocales,consonantes y letras dependiendo de la opción elegida.

**Enunciado del Ejercicio:**

```
/*
    1. Metodo llamado contarVocales el cual debera contar vocales
    2. Metodo llamado contarConsonantes el cual debera contar consonantes
    3. Metodo llamado contarLetras el cual debera contar Letras
    4. Salir
 */
```

**Parte de contar vocales:**

```
public void contarVocales() {
        String vocales;
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("ESCRIBE LA FRASE : ");
        vocales = teclado.nextLine();
        vocales = vocales.toLowerCase();
        char vocal[] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
        int contador = 0;
        boolean esVocal = false;
        char actual;
        for (int i = 0; i < vocales.length(); i++) {
            esVocal = false;
            actual = vocales.charAt(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < vocal.length && !esVocal; j++) {
                if (vocal[j] == actual) {
                    esVocal = true;
                    contador++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("ESTA FRASE TIENE " + contador + " VOCALES");
    }
```

**Parte de contar consonantes:**

```
public void contarConsonantes() {
        String consonantes;
        Scanner teclado1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("ESCRIBE LA FRASE : ");
        consonantes = teclado1.nextLine();
        consonantes = consonantes.toLowerCase();
        char consonante[] = {'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'ñ', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
        int contador = 0;
        boolean esConsonante = false;
        char actual;
        for (int i = 0; i < consonantes.length(); i++) {
            esConsonante = false;
            actual = consonantes.charAt(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < consonante.length && !esConsonante; j++) {
                if (consonante[j] == actual) {
                    esConsonante = true;
                    contador++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("ESTA FRASE TIENE " + contador + " CONSONANTES");
    }
```

**Parte de contar letras:**

```
 public void contarLetras() {
        String letras;
        Scanner teclado2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("ESCRIBE LA FRASE : ");
        letras = teclado2.nextLine();
        letras = letras.toLowerCase();
        char letra[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'ñ', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
        int contador = 0;
        boolean esLetra = false;
        char actual;
        for (int i = 0; i < letras.length(); i++) {
            esLetra = false;
            actual = letras.charAt(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < letra.length && !esLetra; j++) {
                if (letra[j] == actual) {
                    esLetra = true;
                    contador++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("ESTA FRASE TIENE " + contador + " LETRAS");
    }
```

**Parte del main:**

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        int opt;
        CuentaLetras p = new CuentaLetras();
        Scanner op = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(" __________________________________________ ");
        System.out.println("|       MENU CONTAR FRASES JAVIER          |");
        System.out.println("|__________________________________________|");
        System.out.println("|      1. CONTAR VOCALES                   |");
        System.out.println("|__________________________________________|");
        System.out.println("|      2. CONTAR CONSONANTES               |");
        System.out.println("|__________________________________________|");
        System.out.println("|      3. CONTAR LETRAS                    |");
        System.out.println("|__________________________________________|");
        System.out.println("|      4. SALIR                            |");
        System.out.println("|__________________________________________|");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("ELIGE UNA OPCION DEL MENU : ");
        opt = op.nextInt();
        if (opt == 1) {
            p.contarVocales();
        } else if (opt == 2) {
            p.contarConsonantes();
        } else if (opt == 3) {
            p.contarLetras();
        } else if (opt == 4) {
            System.out.println("SALIENDO DEL PROGRAMA");
            System.exit(0);
        } else if (opt != 4) {
            System.out.println("ERROR EJECUTA DE NUEVO EL PROGRAMA Y ESCRIBE UNA OPCION CORRECTA POR FAVOR");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

Y muchas gracias adelantadas y si veis alguna duda sobre el ejercicio no dudéis en preguntarme e iré editando las preguntas. Y si os falla algo no dudéis en preguntarme algo que os falle que intentare hacer una mano. Y muchas gracias a todas las personas que me han ayudado sin vosotros no hubiera podido hacer nada rompiéndome la cabeza una y otra vez y sin vosotros no lo hubiera logrado ya sea calculando la letra del dni y mas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay algunos detalles que no has tomado en cuenta dado que la frase estará también en español debes agregar la vocales con tilde y la u con diéresis. Para las comparaciones yo lo haría de la siguiente manera:

Un arreglo que contenga las vocales como propiedad de la clase estático para que sea usado por todas las instancias, además privado y `final` para que no sea reasignado, aunque los elementos sí se podrían modificar. *Otra opción puede ser usar un Set inmutable.*

```
private static final char[] vocales = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'á', 'é', 'í', 'ó', 'ú', 'ü'};
```

Para buscar vocales puedes crear un método que te devuelva `true` si es vocal o `false` si no lo es:

```
private boolean esVocal(char c) {
    for (char vocal : vocales) {
        if (c == vocal)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Para buscar consonantes puedes crear un método que te devuelva `true` si es consonante o `false` si no lo es. Puedes además ayudarte con el método anterior:

```
private boolean esConsonante(char c) {
    return c >= 'b' && c <= 'z' && !esVocal(c);
}
```

La condición sería que el caracter sea mayor o igual que 'b' y menor o igual que 'z' y que no sea vocal. Así no tienes que comparar el caracter con cada una de las letras.

Para buscar letras puedes crear un método que te devuelva `true` si es letra o `false` si no lo es y te ayudas con los dos métodos anteriores:

```
private boolean esLetra(char c) {
    return esVocal(c) || esConsonante(c);
}
```

La condición sería que el caracter sea vocal o consonante.

Para contar vocales creas un método que reciba como parámetro la frase y haces lo siguiente:

```
public void contarVocales(String frase) {
    int cont = 0;
    for (char c : frase.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
        if (esVocal(c))
            cont++;
    }
    System.out.println("ESTA FRASE TIENE " + cont + " VOCALES");
}
```

Para contar consonantes creas un método que reciba como parámetro la frase y haces lo siguiente:

```
public void contarConsonantes(String frase) {
    int cont = 0;
    for (char c : frase.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
        if (esConsonante(c))
            cont++;
    }
    System.out.println("ESTA FRASE TIENE " + cont + " CONSONANTES");
}
```

Para contar letras creas un método que reciba como parámetro la frase y haces lo siguiente:

```
public void contarLetras(String frase) {
    int cont = 0;
    for (char c : frase.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
        if (esLetra(c))
            cont++;
    }
    System.out.println("ESTA FRASE TIENE " + cont + " LETRAS");
}
```

Por último en las opciones del menú primero le pides al usuario que digite la frase y luego llamas a los métodos pasándole como parámetro la frase digitada:

Si escoge la opción 1:

```
System.out.print("ESCRIBE LA FRASE : ");
contarVocales(op.nextLine());
```

Si escoge la opción 2:

```
System.out.print("ESCRIBE LA FRASE : ");
contarConsonantes(op.nextLine());
```

Si escoge la opción 3:

```
System.out.print("ESCRIBE LA FRASE : ");
contarLetras(op.nextLine());
```

Ten cuidado cuando le pides la opción al usuario ya que está esperando un `int` y si digita otra cosa botará el programa. Además algunas veces el `Scanner` puede fallar cuando pides una línea completa si antes se pidió un número. Lo mejor sería que en lugar de `nextInt()` lo pidas con `nextLine()` y compares Strings en lugar de números.

Además para las comparaciones de la opción elegida del menú puedes usar un `switch` para que se vea "más elegante" en lugar de `if`s.

Comment: muchas gracias lo voy a mirra ya te di la fecha par arriba

Answer (score 1):

Para las vocales, por ejemplo, puedes evitarte el bucle y hacer:

```
letras = teclado.nextLine();
letras = letras.toLowerCase();
vocales = letras.replaceAll("[^aeiou]", "").length();
```

Así eliminas de la frase todas las letras que no son las que le especificas (aeiou en este ejemplo) y cuentas la longitud de la cadena. Para las consonantes y las letras puedes hacer lo mismo.

Comment: le voy a echar un vistaso

Comment: una duda mi ejercicio esta bien explicado lo que busco?

Comment: Sí, el problema se entiende bien, tienes un código y quieres hacerlo más eficiente. Habrá muchas posibles soluciones, yo sólo te he propuesto una de ellas.

Comment: tu solucion parece sencilla y muchas gracias :)

Comment: si esta bien formulada le puedes dar a la fecha de arriba para que lo veas mas personas y también puedan ayudar :)

Answer (score 1):

Compañero, una opción para optimizar el ejercicio creo que sería la que te pongo en el código de debajo. Como ves, en cada método utilizo un condicional **IF** en vez de un bucle FOR, y filtro siempre el String usando el método **.toLowerCase()**. Realmente el código hace lo mismo que el tuyo, pero, como ves, nos ahorramos unas cuantas líneas de código.

Respecto al **menú**, quizás una opción más *elegante* sería usar un **Switch**. En mi propuesta, muestro las opciones al usuario que introduce mediante la clase Scanner en la variable **opcionUsuario**, que es la que maneja el Switch para mostrar la opción deseada.

Método **contarVocales()**:

```
    public static void contarVocales() {
    Scanner src = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Por favor, introduce una frase para contar sus VOCALES:");

    String st = src.nextLine();

    int vocales = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < st.length(); i++) {
        char ch = st.toLowerCase().charAt(i);
        if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u') {
            vocales++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("La frase tiene " + vocales + " vocales.");
}
```

Método **contarConsonantes()**:

```
    public static void contarConsonantes() {
    Scanner src = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Por favor, introduce una frase para contar sus CONSONANTES:");

    String st = src.nextLine();

    int consonantes = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < st.length(); i++) {
        char ch = st.toLowerCase().charAt(i);
        if (ch != 'a' && ch != 'e' && ch != 'i' && ch != 'o' && ch != 'u' 
                && ch != ' ') {
            consonantes++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("La frase tiene " + consonantes + " consonantes.");
}
```

Método **contarLetras()**:

```
    public static void contarLetras() {
    Scanner src = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Por favor, introduce una frase para contar el número de LETRAS:");

    String st = src.nextLine();

    int letras = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < st.length(); i++) {
        char ch = st.toLowerCase().charAt(i);
        if (ch != ' ') {
            letras++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("La frase tiene " + letras + " letras.");
}
```

**Menú**:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner src = new Scanner(System.in);
    int opcionUsuario;
    
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(" __________________________________________ ");
    System.out.println("|       MENU CONTAR FRASES JAVIER          |");
    System.out.println("|__________________________________________|");
    System.out.println("|      1. CONTAR VOCALES                   |");
    System.out.println("|__________________________________________|");
    System.out.println("|      2. CONTAR CONSONANTES               |");
    System.out.println("|__________________________________________|");
    System.out.println("|      3. CONTAR LETRAS                    |");
    System.out.println("|__________________________________________|");
    System.out.println("|      4. SALIR                            |");
    System.out.println("|__________________________________________|");
    System.out.println();
    
    System.out.print("ELIGE UNA OPCION DEL MENU, 4 PARA SALIR: ");
    opcionUsuario = src.nextInt();
    
    switch(opcionUsuario){
        case 1:
            contarVocales();
            break;
        case 2:
            contarConsonantes();
            break;
        case 3:
            contarLetras();
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Hasta pronto!!");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("ERROR EJECUTA DE NUEVO EL PROGRAMA Y ESCRIBE UNA OPCION CORRECTA POR FAVOR\"");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: vale lo voy a mirra y mucha gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo el ejercicio más o menos como lo habría hecho yo, todos los cambios están explicados en los comentarios. Si no entiendes algo no dudes en preguntar!

```
public void contarLetras() {
        String letras;
        Scanner teclado2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("ESCRIBE LA FRASE : ");
        letras = teclado2.nextLine();
        letras = letras.toLowerCase();
        int contador = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < letras.length(); i++) {
            //Los caracteres españoles en minúsculas están representados por los códigos del 97 al 122
            //Así solo hay que comprobar que la letra esté entre esos valores. Esto se debe a que un char es
            //realmente la representación en caracter de un número. Esto es mucho más rápido que iterar un array
            //comparando cada valor individualmente
            int codigoLetra = letras.charAt(i);
            if(codigoLetra >= 97 && codigoLetra <= 122){
                contador++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("ESTA FRASE TIENE " + contador + " LETRAS");
    }

    public void contarVocales() {
        String vocales;
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("ESCRIBE LA FRASE : ");
        vocales = teclado.nextLine();
        vocales = vocales.toLowerCase();
        char vocal[] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
        int contador = 0;
        boolean esVocal = false;
        char actual;
        //En este caso, un loop con 5 letras no es excesivamente largo así que habría poca diferencia.
        //Personalmente prefiero usar break; en loops pequeños en vez de condiciones de salida
        //Pero no estoy seguro de qué es mejor, eso si, quedaría algo más corto
        /*for(int i = 0; i < vocales.length(); i++){
            actual = vocales.charAt(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < vocal.length; j++) {
                if (vocal[j] == actual) {
                    contador++;
                    //El break; interrumpe la actual iteración del bucle j, volviendo al bucle anterior con la i
                    break;
                }
            }
        }*/
        for (int i = 0; i < vocales.length(); i++) {
            esVocal = false;
            actual = vocales.charAt(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < vocal.length && !esVocal; j++) {
                if (vocal[j] == actual) {
                    esVocal = true;
                    contador++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("ESTA FRASE TIENE " + contador + " VOCALES");
    }

    public void contarConsonantes() {
        String consonantes;
        Scanner teclado1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("ESCRIBE LA FRASE : ");
        consonantes = teclado1.nextLine();
        consonantes = consonantes.toLowerCase();

        int contador = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < consonantes.length(); i++) {
            //Aquí aplicaré la misma lógica que en contarLetras, con una excepción para las 5 vocales
            int codigoLetra = consonantes.charAt(i);
            if(codigoLetra >= 97 && codigoLetra <= 122){
                //Hago la comparación con chars porque es más fácil que recordar los valores numéricos de esas letras
                if(codigoLetra == 'a' || codigoLetra == 'e' ||
                    codigoLetra == 'i' || codigoLetra == 'o' || codigoLetra == 'u'){
                    //Si es una vocal, uso continue, que salta a la siguiente iteración del loop,
                    //evitando que se sume el contador
                    continue;
                }
                contador++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("ESTA FRASE TIENE " + contador + " CONSONANTES");
    }

    public void printMenu(){
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(" __________________________________________ ");
        System.out.println("|       MENU CONTAR FRASES JAVIER          |");
        System.out.println("|__________________________________________|");
        System.out.println("|      1. CONTAR VOCALES                   |");
        System.out.println("|__________________________________________|");
        System.out.println("|      2. CONTAR CONSONANTES               |");
        System.out.println("|__________________________________________|");
        System.out.println("|      3. CONTAR LETRAS                    |");
        System.out.println("|__________________________________________|");
        System.out.println("|      4. SALIR                            |");
        System.out.println("|__________________________________________|");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("ELIGE UNA OPCION DEL MENU : ");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int opt;
        CuentaLetras p = new CuentaLetras();
        Scanner op = new Scanner(System.in);
        //He movido el menú a su propio método para tener esto más limpio
        p.printMenu();
        //Bucle infinito, ahora el programa no acabará hasta que pulses 4 en el menú
        while(true) {
            opt = op.nextInt();
            //Switch, evitamos el uso de else if repetidos con la misma comparación
            switch (opt) {
                case 1:
                    p.contarVocales();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    p.contarConsonantes();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    p.contarLetras();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                //El código entrará al default cuando ninguna de las anteriores sea válida, 
                // así siempre repetirá el menú en caso de error
                default:
                    p.printMenu();
            }
        }
    }
```

Como ves, el código de contar letras es mucho más pequeño y tan solo verifica que la letra esté entre dos valores, más rápido imposible (creo!)

Comment: gracias lo voy a mirrar